# responsive background with min and max

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want make a responsive background with image when I used `background-size: contain;` in small screen that was awesome but in large screen my image is too large. how I can Determine maximum width and height just using HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a media query to switch `background-size` depending on screen size. For example, if your image is 640px wide:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/640/480);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media(min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    background-size: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use media queries in your css.

```
@media (background-size: contain){
    // rules for when the background-size: contain is applied
}
```

Comment: That's not how media queries work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries